# Stored procedure: reduce code duplication using temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, refactoring, temp-tables

After many changes to my stored procedure, I think it needs to re-factoring , mainly because of code duplication. How to overcome these duplications:

```
IF @transExist > 0 BEGIN
    IF @transType = 1 BEGIN --INSERT
        SELECT
            a.dayDate,
            a.shiftName,
            a.limit,
            b.startTimeBefore,
            b.endTimeBefore,
            b.dayAdd,
            b.name,
            b.overtimeHours,
            c.startTime,
            c.endTime
        INTO 
            #Residence1
        FROM 
            #ShiftTrans a 
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
                ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
            INNER JOIN ShiftDetails c
                ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId AND 
                c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId;

        SET @is_trans = 1;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        RETURN ;
    END
END ELSE BEGIN
    IF @employeeExist > 0 BEGIN
        SELECT
            a.dayDate,
            a.shiftName,
            a.limit,
            b.startTimeBefore,
            b.endTimeBefore,
            b.dayAdd,
            b.name,
            b.overtimeHours,
            c.startTime,
            c.endTime
        INTO 
            #Residence2
        FROM 
            #ShiftEmployees a 
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
                ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
            INNER JOIN ShiftDetails c
                ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId AND 
                c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId;

            SET @is_trans = 0;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END
END;

IF @is_trans = 1 BEGIN
    WITH CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans AS (
        SELECT * FROM #Residence1
    )

    UPDATE t1
    SET 
        t1.over_time = t1.over_time 
          + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(overtimeHours as varchar(2)),2)
             +':00:00' As Time) 
          + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)),2)
             +':00:00' As Time),
        t1.day_flag = t1.day_flag + 'R1',
        t1.day_desc = 'R::' 
          + CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.shiftName +'[ '
          + CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.name +' ]'
    FROM 
        rr_overtime AS t1
        INNER JOIN CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans 
            ON t1.[trans_date] = CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.[dayDate]
    WHERE 
        t1.emp_num = @empNum;

    UPDATE rr_overtime 
    SET 
        over_time = CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(0 as varchar(2)),2)+':00:00' As Time),
        day_flag = day_flag +'R2'
    WHERE 
        trans_date = @TomorrowDate AND 
        emp_num = @empNum;

END ELSE BEGIN
    WITH CTE_Residence_Overtime AS (
        SELECT * FROM #Residence2
    )

    UPDATE t1
    SET 
        t1.over_time = CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(overtimeHours as varchar(2)), 2) 
          +':00:00' As Time)
        + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)),2)+':00:00' As Time),
        t1.day_flag = t1.day_flag + 'R1',
        t1.day_desc = 'R::' 
          + CTE_Residence_Overtime.shiftName +'[ '
          + CTE_Residence_Overtime.name +' ]'
    FROM 
        rr_overtime AS t1
        INNER JOIN CTE_Residence_Overtime 
            ON t1.[trans_date] = CTE_Residence_Overtime.[dayDate]
    WHERE 
        t1.emp_num = @empNum ;

    UPDATE rr_overtime 
    SET 
        over_time = CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(0 as varchar(2)),2)+':00:00' As Time),
        day_flag = day_flag +'R2'
    WHERE 
        trans_date = @TomorrowDate AND 
        emp_num = @empNum;

END
```

Comment: What duplications are you getting?

Comment: @TabAlleman : i'm talking about duplication in code not in the data .

Comment: @just_name That will be fine if you use some of functions to avoid duplicated computing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following to avoid the duplication. Basically create your temporary table first (I've guessed the datatypes), then use only this table for the insert since you're using if's it's going to be one or the other that inserts to this.

Then you don't need CTE's if you're doing Select * from table so just call direct from the table. Since the table will only have data from one select or the other and the field names are the same etc we can just use one update for this and don't need anymore if's:

```
Create table #Residence (dayDate varchar(9), shiftName varchar(20), limit int, startTimeBefore time, endTimeBefore time, dayAdd int, name varchar(30), overtimeHours int, startTime time, endTime time)

IF @transExist > 0 

       BEGIN

        IF @transType = 1 --INSERT
           BEGIN
          Insert into #Residence
          SELECT a.dayDate,a.shiftName,a.limit,b.startTimeBefore,b.endTimeBefore,b.dayAdd,b.name,b.overtimeHours,c.startTime,c.endTime
           FROM #ShiftTrans a RIGHT OUTER JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
           ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
           INNER JOIN ShiftDetails c
           ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId AND c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId;
           END
         ELSE
           BEGIN
           RETURN ;
           END
       END

  ELSE
     BEGIN

        IF @employeeExist > 0
            BEGIN
            Insert into #Residence
            SELECT a.dayDate,a.shiftName,a.limit,b.startTimeBefore,b.endTimeBefore,b.dayAdd,b.name,b.overtimeHours,c.startTime,c.endTime
            FROM #ShiftEmployees a RIGHT OUTER JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
            ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
            INNER JOIN ShiftDetails c
            ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId AND c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId;
            END
        ELSE
           BEGIN
             RETURN ;
           END
     END;

    UPDATE t1 
    SET t1.over_time = t1.over_time + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(overtimeHours  as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time) +
    CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time),
    t1.day_flag = t1.day_flag + 'R1',
    t1.day_desc = 'R::' +R.shiftName +'[ '+ R.name +' ]'

    FROM rr_overtime AS t1
    INNER JOIN #Residence R
    ON t1.[trans_date] = R.[dayDate]
    WHERE t1.emp_num = @empNum ;

    UPDATE rr_overtime SET over_time = CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(0 as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time),
    day_flag = day_flag +'R2'
    WHERE trans_date = @TomorrowDate AND emp_num = @empNum;
```

Comment: Tip: You should always use `SELECT ... INTO #blah FROM tab1, tab2, WHERE 1 = 2` to create your temporary tables, that way you always have the right datatypes and never suffer from collation issues. The only downside is when you want to make them NULL-able when they aren't and/or when there is an IDENTITY() field; but those you can work around by simply adding 0.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the code, it looks like this should work:

```
WITH CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans AS (
    SELECT
        a.dayDate,
        a.shiftName,
        a.limit,
        b.startTimeBefore,
        b.endTimeBefore,
        b.dayAdd,
        b.name,
        b.overtimeHours,
        c.startTime,
        c.endTime
    FROM
        ( 
            select dayDate, shiftName, limit
            from #ShiftTrans
            where (@transExist > 0 and @transType = 1)
        union all
            select dayDate, shiftName, limit 
            from #ShiftEmployees
            where (not (@transExist>0 and @transType=1)) and @employeeExist>0
        ) a
    JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
        ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
    JOIN ShiftDetails c
        ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId AND 
        c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId
)

UPDATE t1
SET 
    t1.over_time = t1.over_time 
      + CAST(CAST(overtimeHours as varchar(2))+':00:00' As Time) 
      + CAST(CAST(@total_min    as varchar(2))+':00:00' As Time),
    t1.day_flag = t1.day_flag + 'R1',
    t1.day_desc = 'R::' + CTE.shiftName +'[ ' + CTE.name +' ]'
FROM 
    rr_overtime AS t1
    INNER JOIN CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans CTE
        ON t1.[trans_date] = CTE.[dayDate]
WHERE 
    t1.emp_num = @empNum;

UPDATE rr_overtime 
SET 
    over_time = CAST('00:00:00' As Time),
    day_flag = day_flag +'R2'
WHERE 
    trans_date = @TomorrowDate AND 
    emp_num = @empNum;
```

This makes an union all select to both of the temp. tables, but only fetches data from the correct one based on the variables, and uses that as the CTE for the update. I also removed the outer join because the table was also involved in an inner join.

Although this can shorten the code, it is not always the best way to do things, because it might cause more complex query plan to be used causing performance issues.

I also removed the right(2,...) functions from time conversion, since time conversion works without leading zero too, and the last one was just fixed 00:00:00.

Comment: You should also add the check for the variables before this to exit completely if no update is needed, didn't include it to this.

Answer (score 3):

The code creating the temporary table looks identical, so I've merged it into the CTE. The code in the update has minor differences which can be handled with the `CASE` statement. The `CASE` Statement can be moved into the `CTE` if required.

So give This a try:

```
IF @transExist > 0
BEGIN
  IF @transType <> 1 RETURN ELSE SET @is_trans = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN  
  IF @employeeExist <= 0 RETURN ELSE SET @is_trans = 0
END

;WITH CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans
AS
(
      SELECT a.dayDate,a.shiftName,a.limit,b.startTimeBefore,b.endTimeBefore,b.dayAdd,b.name,b.overtimeHours,c.startTime,c.endTime
       FROM #ShiftTrans a RIGHT OUTER JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
       ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
       INNER JOIN ShiftDetails c
       ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId AND c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId;
)

UPDATE t1 
SET t1.over_time =  
    CASE 
    WHEN @Is_Trans = 1 THEN
        t1.over_time + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(overtimeHours  as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time) +
        CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time) 
    ELSE
        CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(overtimeHours  as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time) +
       CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time)
    END,
    t1.day_flag = t1.day_flag + 'R1',
    t1.day_desc = 'R::' +CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.shiftName +'[ '+ CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.name +' ]'
FROM rr_overtime AS t1
INNER JOIN CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans 
ON t1.[trans_date] = CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.[dayDate]
WHERE t1.emp_num = @empNum ;

UPDATE rr_overtime SET over_time = CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(0 as varchar(2)), 2)+':00:00' As Time),
day_flag = day_flag +'R2'
WHERE trans_date = @TomorrowDate AND emp_num = @empNum;
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use dynamic query

In insert query only the from table is varies depends on condition,right?
So use something like this

```
DECLARE @FromTable NVARCHAR(250)
IF @transExist > 0 BEGIN
IF @transType = 1 BEGIN --INSERT
    SELECT @FromTable = '#ShiftTrans'
    SET @is_trans = 1;
END ELSE BEGIN
    RETURN ;
END
END ELSE BEGIN
IF @employeeExist > 0 BEGIN

        SELECT @FromTable = '#ShiftEmployees'
        SET @is_trans = 0;
END ELSE BEGIN
    RETURN;
END
END;

DECLARE @DynamicQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT
        a.dayDate,
        a.shiftName,
        a.limit,
        b.startTimeBefore,
        b.endTimeBefore,
        b.dayAdd,
        b.name,
        b.overtimeHours,
        c.startTime,
        c.endTime
    INTO 
        #Residence1
    FROM 
        '+@FromTable+' a 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
            ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
        INNER JOIN ShiftDetails c
            ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId AND 
            c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId'


EXECUTE (@DynamicQuery)
```

SAMe way create dynamic query for the update part also...

Thejus T V

Answer (score 2):

First part is combining the #Trans and #Employee using `UNION ALL`. But since you still have to differentiate the two in order to do

```
t1.over_time = 
    t1.over_time   --<------------- One is cumalative add and the other isn't
    + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(overtimeHours as varchar(2)),2)
        +':00:00' As Time) 
    + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)),2)
        +':00:00' As Time),
```

for Trans and

```
t1.over_time = 
    CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(overtimeHours as varchar(2)), 2) 
        +':00:00' As Time)
    + CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)),2)
        +':00:00' As Time),
```

for Employee, I'm adding EmployeeType column in the CTE. Also, made some assumptions on the destination datatype in **rr_datatype** table. If that is, in fact, `TIME` or `DATETIME` or some other variant, you should be using `DATEADD` function instead. [MSDN page here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)..

And lastly, the second `UPDATE` statement can also be combined into the first if you're only intending to update those records involved in the first `UPDATE` and not trying to update the entire table.

```
; WITH TransAndEmployee AS (
    SELECT 'T' AS EmployeeType, dayDate, shiftName, limit
    FROM #ShiftTrans 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'E' AS EmployeeType, dayDate, shiftName, limit
    FROM #ShiftEmployees
), PoundOvertime AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TransAndEmployee a 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN #ResidenceOvertime b
        ON a.dayDate = b.dayDate
    INNER JOIN ShiftDetails c
        ON c.shiftId = a.shiftId 
        AND c.shiftTypeId = b.shiftTypeId;
)
UPDATE ot
SET over_time = DATEADD(mi,@total_min,
                    DATEADD(hh,overtimeHours,CASE WHEN EmployeeType = 'T' THEN over_time ELSE '0:00' END)
                ),
    day_flag = day_flag + 'R1',
    day_desc = 'R::' + CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.shiftName + '[ ' + CTE_Residence_Overtime_trans.name + ' ]'
FROM rr_overtime ot
INNER JOIN PoundOvertime p
    ON ot.[trans_date] = p.[dayDate]
WHERE ot.emp_num = @empNum


UPDATE rr_overtime 
SET 
    over_time = CAST('00:00:00' As Time), -- You can probably do over_time = '00:00' if over_time is TIME
    day_flag = day_flag +'R2'
WHERE 
    trans_date = @TomorrowDate AND 
    emp_num = @empNum;
```

Another assumption I made... below looked a bit strange to me. I assumed you were trying to add "minutes" ... however this string a manipulation seems to be adding it to hours. I "corrected" it... let me know if that was a poor assumption.

```
+ CAST(RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@total_min  as varchar(2)),2)
    +':00:00' As Time),
```